# Session variable generate error

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, session, .net-2.0

i am trying to use session but i get error:

> The name 'Session' does not exist in the current context

what i am doing wrong i am using n-tier and in this page there is no page load function. Session is having link with page_load?

```
public bool CheckDate(ArrayList roles, string username, string password, string locat)
{
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SQLCONN"].ToString());
    SqlCommand chkdt = new SqlCommand("AccountRoles_GetDateForID", conn);
    chkdt.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    chkdt.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@userName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 32));
    chkdt.Parameters["@userName"].Value = username;
    chkdt.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@password", SqlDbType.VarChar, 250));
    chkdt.Parameters["@password"].Value = password;
    chkdt.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@location", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50));
    chkdt.Parameters["@location"].Value = locat;
    conn.Open();
    try
    {
        DateTime ddt = new DateTime();
        DateTime tdd = DateTime.Parse(DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString());
        SqlDataReader reader = chkdt.ExecuteReader();
        if (reader.HasRows)
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                if (reader["ExpiryDate"].ToString() == "")
                {
                }
                else
                {
                    ddt = DateTime.Parse(reader["ExpiryDate"].ToString());
                }
            }
        }
        TimeSpan ts = ddt.Subtract(tdd);
        day = ts.Days.ToString();
        Session["days"] = day;
        if (tdd.Equals(ddt))
        {               
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        conn.Close();
        chkdt.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your method is not in a class that inherits from `Page`, the `Session` property isn't inherited.

Use the `Current` property of the `HttpContext` class to access the current http context where the `Session` collection is:

```
HttpContext.Current.Session["days"] = day;
```

Comment: thank you very much @Guffa. now can we treat it as simple Session variable?

Comment: @RaniaUmair: It's the same collection as you access using the `Session` property in the `Page` class. It's just a shortcut to the collection in the http context object.

Answer (score 1):

Anyway, you can shorten your code using the following trick:

```
chkdt.Parameters.Add("@userName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 32).Value = username;
chkdt.Parameters.Add("@password", SqlDbType.VarChar, 250).Value = password;
chkdt.Parameters.Add("@location", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = locat;
```

And don't read a data reader twice:

```
DateTime? dt = reader["ExpiryDate"] as DateTime?; // if column has DateTime-compatible type
if (dt.HasValue)
{
}
else
{
}
```

And close data reader. Even better wrap everything in a using block(s):

```
using (SqlConnection conn = ...)
using (SqlCommand chkdt = ...)
{
   ...
   using (SqlDataReder reader = ...)
   {
      ...
   }
}
```